# How to stop virtual server on AWS programatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I am planning to create virtual server(Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Web on Windows Server 2019) in AWS but the costing is too high for me, to reduce the price I wanted to stop my virtual server automatically for some hours by using other AWS service.

1. How can I shutdown the virtual server?
2. Will I be able to shutdown it?
3. How AMI and EC2 are different in nature ?

After searching by hours I found that EC2 and RDS can be shutdown automatically but didn't find any article related to that.

Link for Virtual Server I want to created :
https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-urbgwl6rh6cuu?sr=0-1&ref_=beagle&applicationId=AWSMPContessa

Link for help:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/terminating-instances.html

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "shutdown"? Amazon EC2 has two relevant actions: `Stop` means that the instance turns off but can be turned on again (like hitting the power button on a computer), while `Terminate` means that the instance should be _deleted_ and cannot be turned on again. Which one do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

1. To terminate an instance using the console

Before you terminate an instance, verify that you won't lose any data by checking that your Amazon EBS volumes won't be deleted on termination and that you've copied any data that you need from your instance store volumes to persistent storage, such as Amazon EBS or Amazon S3.

Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.

In the navigation pane, choose Instances.

Select the instance, and choose Instance state, Terminate instance.

Choose Terminate when prompted for confirmation.

2. Yes
3. The EC2 is used for creating the virtual server instance. The AMI is the EC2 virtual machines image. ECS provides container services such as docker and the AWS lambda is used to run the code without a server.

You can learn more about the differences in [this link](https://medium.com/programmingnotes/aws-compute-ec2-ami-ecs-aws-lambda-12240db1b003#:%7E:text=The%20EC2%20is%20used%20for,the%20code%20without%20a%20server.)

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a solution that shuts down ec2 instances for some period of time you can write a custom script in Lambda that is triggered by an Eventbridge scheduler at which you want to start/stop the instances.

create two Eventbridge schedule triggers for the Lambda script: one for starting and the other for stopping instances. The code will evaluate the status of the instances and perform the appropriate action. For example, if an instance is currently stopped, the Lambda will start it, and if an instance is running, it will stop it.

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    def stop_start_instances(instance_ids):
        ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
        instances = ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=instance_ids)

        for instance in instances:
            if instance.state['Name'] == 'running':
                instance.stop()
                print(f"Instance {instance.id} has been stopped.")
            elif instance.state['Name'] == 'stopped':
                instance.start()
                print(f"Instance {instance.id} has been started.")
            else:
                print(f"Instance {instance.id} is in an intermediate state: {instance.state['Name']}. Unable to perform the desired action.")

    # Specify the instance IDs to check and perform actions on
    instance_ids = ['<INSTANCE_ID_1>','<INSTANCE_ID_2>']

    # Call the function to stop or start the instances based on their current state
    stop_start_instances(instance_ids)
```

You can refer to the following for the solution -

https://medium.com/@TechStoryLines/automate-the-process-of-stopping-ec2-instances-for-a-specific-duration-and-then-automatically-9ce434122170

https://techstorylines.hashnode.dev/automate-the-process-of-stopping-ec2-instances-for-a-specific-duration-and-then-automatically-restarting-them

I am still working on an RDS solution, even that requirement can be achieved in a similar manner.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34646521)

Comment: Yeah, got it. We will make sure to remember this in the future. Thank you